# AngularJS ng-repeat jQuery find returns only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing my first AngularJS app, and came across this problem with jQuery find function. Basically what I am trying to do, is that I have an custom HTML component . It contains list of buttons using ng-repeat directive. Each has it's own ng-click listener, and in it's callback I want to find all app-item elements, but sadly it only returns me the first one.

I think this is the case I should use **link**, but I cannot come with it myself.

Part of app-screen.html:

```
<div>    
    <div ng-repeat="error in _errorData.errors">
        <button class="app-item" ng-click="_onApplicationContainerClick($event)">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                {{error.date}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                {{error.errorID}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                {{error.message}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

AppScreen directive:

```
angular.module('ErrorViewer').directive('appScreen', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'src/view/scene/app-screen.html',
        controller: 'AppScreenController'
    };
});
```

Part of AppScreenController:

```
$scope._onApplicationContainerClick = function (e) {
    // some executions
    _collapseErrorData();
};

var _collapseErrorData = function () {
    var elems = $element.find( '.app-item' );
    // Should return array of ng-repeated elements!
}
```

Comment: where does $element comes from? did you tried angular.element.find('.app-item')?

Comment: It's just part of the controller, it comes from controller declaration:

`angular.module( 'Smth' ).controller( 'AppScreenController', [ '$document', '$scope', '$element', 
function ($document, $scope, $element) {`

Comment: ok, then what is this injected `$element`?it's jQuery, jQuery lit or angular.element?

Answer (score 2):

ng-repeat is rendered during the render phase (when the $watch handlers are being executed). During the compile and link phases, you only have access to the template. That is the reason you're only seeing one element.

To hook into the after-render phase, you can use $timeout:

```
app.controller('AppScreenController', function($scope, $timeout) {
     var _collapseErrorData = function () {
        $timeout(function() {
            var elems = $element.find( '.app-item' );
            // Should return array of ng-repeated elements!
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: From my point of view, it should re-render the stage after ng-repeat watch expression changed. And in my case _collapseErrorData isn't executing at the same time ( because you cannot click not-redered element ). So shouldn't this elements be already on stage?